# Incremented virtual in a select with a group constraint with MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, group

I would like to select datas from an alone table with two columns, for a value in the first column there may be only one or multiples different values for the second columnn, but one value in the second can be associated to only one in the first. Both are not unique individually and even concatenated. Example :

```
col_1    col_2    
=====    =====    
a        x       
a        y        
b        z        
c        w        
b        z        
c        w
```

Let's say the col_1 is a group, col_2 a group chapter, and I need to associate a number to each of these chapters relative to their group; needs this number to be deterministic so rows can move and number kept during the lifecycle of the table. The result of the query should be then :

```
col_1    col_2    generated_col
=====    =====    =============
a        y        1
a        x        2
b        z        1
c        w        1
```

col_1 + col_2 become unique in the result set, so each new value of col_2 for the same col_1 value gets a +1 to his generated_col.

Is there a way to do this directly in a select query ?

Important note : the MySQL server is on version 5.5

Comment: Since you have no primary key, neither a timestamp or anything to determine the insertion order, you cannot know that *a,y* is *1* and *a,x* is *2*. It could as well be *a,x,1* and *a,y,2*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working as expected :

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col2) 
        FROM yourTable t2 
        WHERE t2.numcmd = t1.numcmd 
        AND t2.col2 <= t1.col2
    ) generated_col
FROM yourTable t1
```

Largely inspired by Tim's answer

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, you may use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```sql
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_1 ORDER BY col_3) generated_col
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY col_1, col_3;
```

A workaround, for MySQL 5.7 and earlier:

```sql
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.col_1 = t1.col_1 AND t2.col_3 <= t1.col_3) generated_col
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY col_1, col_3;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it runs on 5.5 unfortunately.. editing the post

Comment: I have added an option for earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: That is not far, but that col_3 is not reliable. I edited the post to remove it